# How to implement automated testing in jsPsych web apps (No UI framework)?

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, jspsych

So i'm doing some contract work and need to test some small web apps. They are built with the jsPsych framework and bundled with Webpack. I don't know how to test these apps since I have no access to the UI.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```html
import {initJsPsych} from 'jspsych';
import htmlKeyboardResponse from '@jspsych/plugin-html-keyboard-response';

const jsPsych = initJsPsych();

const trial = {
  type: htmlKeyboardResponse,
  stimulus: 'Hello world!',
}

jsPsych.run([trial]);
```

This is basically how the whole app is setup. You just define a trial object with the necessary parameters and then put them in an array for jsPsych to run. jsPsych spits out the html on the page. I saw this article: https://dev.to/thawkin3/how-to-unit-test-html-and-vanilla-javascript-without-a-ui-framework-4io on testing without UI framworks but I don't have an HTML file. The HTML file that comes out from the build dosen't have anything in the body since all the trials are rendered dynamically.

How do I test this?